# How do i change color on inputs in a selected row

Tags: jquery

What can i add to my JS to toggle the class of the text in the inputs? at the moment the row background gets .remove toggled, but I can not figure out how to toggle class of the text inside the input.

My HTML:

```
<div class='row shopping'>
    <div><input type='text' id='item' value='1'></div>
    <div><input type='text' id='cost' value='1'></div>
    <div><input type='text' id='group' value='1'></div>
    <div><input type='text' id='code' value='1'></div>
</div>
```

MY JS:

```
$('.shopping').click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('remove');
 });
```

MY CSS:

```
.remove{
   background-color:red;
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the following.

```js
$(function() {
  $('.shopping').click(function() {
    $("input", this).toggleClass('remove');
  });
});
```

```css
.remove {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='row shopping'>
  <div><input type='text' id='item' value='1'></div>
  <div><input type='text' id='cost' value='1'></div>
  <div><input type='text' id='group' value='1'></div>
  <div><input type='text' id='code' value='1'></div>
</div>
<div class='row shopping'>
  <div><input type='text' id='item' value='2'></div>
  <div><input type='text' id='cost' value='2'></div>
  <div><input type='text' id='group' value='2'></div>
  <div><input type='text' id='code' value='2'></div>
</div>
```

When the `click` event is called, `this` relates to the element that was clicked or called upon. We then want to target the `input` elements within that element.

The selector `$("input", this)` is the same as `$(this).find("input")`, so either can be used.

Answer (score 0):

In this code:

```
$('.shopping').click(function(){
  $(this).toggleClass('remove');
});
```

The keyword `this` refers to the element which has the `click` handler attached to it, which in this case is any element with the `shopping` class.  Without altering the markup, you can instead target the `<input>` elements *within* that `.shopping` element:

```
$('.shopping input').click(function(){
  $(this).toggleClass('remove');
});
```

In this case, `this` would refer to the `<input>` since that's the element which is getting the `click` handler attached to it.